# Set width of ConstraintLayout to match_parrent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want my ContraintLayout width is match with parent but not work.

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    //Other View

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            //Child View

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Result**
[image: Result Image]

Comment: What happens if you add `android:orientaation="horizontal"` to the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Try working with `layout_weights` that might help you

Comment: ```orientation``` and ```weight``` not affecting

Answer (score 1):

Your **`ConstraintLayout`** is matching its parent, which in turn is **`LinearLayout`**. If you want the **`ConstraintLayout`** to flex upto the entire screen, change this:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to this:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```